# How can I study the monotonicity of the following function? without using derivatives.

Tags: functions

How can I study the monotonicity  of the following function? 
$$f(x) = |x-4| + |x-1|$$
Shall I divide it into 2 functions?if so then how can I obtain the results for the whole function?

How can I study even & odd?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: divide into case , when $x\geq 4$ , when $ 1 \leq x \leq 4$ and when $x \leq 1$

Comment: By checking derivatives?  Some case analysis is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple: such functions have points  at which they're not differentiable and they alternate monotonicity on the intervals determined by these points. As this particular one tends to $+\infty$ when $x$ tends to $\pm\infty$, you can readily deduce the following table:
$$\begin{array}{r|ccccccc}
x&-\infty&&1&&4&&+\infty\\
\hline
f(x)&+\infty&&&&&&+\infty\\
&&\searrow &&&&\nearrow\\
&&&3&=\mkern-2mu=&3
\end{array}$$

Comment: without using differentiation.

Comment: I didn't: such functions are affine functions by intervals. We don't need differentiation to know their monotonicity.